# Using grep to read a log for pattern1 in the file and print only lines containing pattern1. Stop searching when pattern2 is found in the file

Tags: android, python, awk, sed, grep

Using `grep/sed/awk` I want to search for `pattern1` until `pattern2` is found in a file and print the results containing only `pattern1`.

I don't want the lines between the range of pattern1 and pattern2 for which there are many solutions in this site. Please help.

I tried the following with no results:

adb logcat | grep -i 'pattern1' | grep -m 1 'pattern2'

Looks like `'|'` makes it an `AND condition` and the strings that I am looking for, are not in the same line. They are in different lines.

**Updated:** The solutions work in the terminal but not in a script. Can someone help with finding out why it's not working in a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sed to stop printing after pattern2 is found:

```
adb logcat | sed  '/pattern2/q' | grep -i 'pattern1'
```

Or use sed to both print pattern1 and quit after pattern2:

```
adb logcat | sed  -n '/pattern1/p;/pattern2/q'
```

Comment: Follow-up question. The given solution works fine in the terminal, but when I use it in the Python script, it does not seem to quit when pattern2 is found.

Comment: please post a new question explaining how you tried to use the command line in python, what you expected it to do and what actually happened. you can put a link to this question in your new question.

Answer (score 1):

The can be done with a single call to sed:

```
adb logcat | sed -n '/pattern2/q; /pattern1/p'
```

Alternatively, this can be done with a single call to `awk`:

```
adb logcat | awk '/pattern2/{exit} /pattern1/'
```

Comment: Follow-up question. The given solution for awk works fine in the terminal, but when I use it in the Python script, it does not seem to quit when pattern2 is found.