# sed does not quit when used along with adb logcat in a script

Tags: android, sed, adb, android-logcat

[This is a follow-up question to the solution provided in this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690899/using-grep-to-read-a-log-for-pattern1-in-the-file-and-print-only-lines-containin)

This is the code in my script:

```
cmd = "adb logcat | sed  -n '/pattern1/p;/pattern2/q'"
getLogs,error = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

`adb logcat | sed  -n '/pattern1/p;/pattern2/q'` works fine in the terminal, but sed does not quit when the same code is used in the script.

I dont want to use '`adb logcat -d |`' here because I want the script to run when I am doing something in the device and not after I have finished doing the user-action.

Comment: it seems that everything is in order except for the command string which might mess up backslashes. please try using raw python strings: `cmd = r"adb logcat | ..."`

Comment: Tried it, that did not fix the script. The command script is still not quitting when pattern2 is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping `sed` into `bash` and then into `python` is bad karma.

```
import subprocess

def logcat_iterator(options, display_pattern, quit_pattern):
    popen = subprocess.Popen(['adb', 'shell', 'logcat {}'.format(options)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    iterator = iter(popen.stdout.readline, b'')
    for line in iterator:
        if len(line) > 0:
            if line.find(quit_pattern) > 0:
                break
            elif line.find(display_pattern) > 0:
                yield line
```

Use it like this:

```
for l in logcat_iterator('-b main -v time', 'Displayed', 'Displayed com.android.settings/.Settings'):
    print l
```